# Flex shrinking when neighbour wraps

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How can I make the shrink element "shrink" when the flex container below grows as a result of flex-wrapping. What is happening now is that new space created below the container instead of shrinking the one above. For some reason flex-grow and flex-shrink are not working expectedly whenever wrap happens. I want everything to fit within the viewport so that the user does not need to scroll.

[image: Here is an example of what I want to do]

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-container>* {
  text-align: center;
}

.shrink {
  background-color: #c0caad;
  padding-top: 30%;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 100vw;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.grow {
  height: 20vh;
  width: 30vw;
  background-color: #9da9a0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.grow>* {
  border: 5px solid #654c4f;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #b26e63;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="main-container">
    <div class="shrink">Shrink</div>
    <div class="grow">
      <div class="growItems">Wrap</div>
      <div class="growItems">Wrap</div>
      <div class="growItems">Wrap</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you create a markup image of your desired result?

Comment: not sure I understand where you're going with this - you want shrink, with flex-shrink set to 0, to shrink when wrap shrinks? do you have a more...tangible example where one can see the desired end effect or utility?

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion, I've changed the image and added more to the description I hope this clears things up.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few concerns in your CSS. See the working snippet below.

#### 1. `flex-shrink: 0;` prevents it from shrinking.

For flex-children to be flexibly growing and shrinking, you'd probably want `flex: 1;` or some other `shrink/grow` values than `0`.

#### 2. explicit height of `80vh` and `20vh` make them of static height.

That is, they will remain of those specific `height` rather than flexibly changing their relational heights as you indicated in your drawing. You'd want to remove those values.

#### 3. `padding-top: 30%` pushes the content down, forcing the height

I wonder if you included it just to push the placeholder text down. But in any case, it's one of the factors that stops the `shrink` from shrinking.

#### 4. `width: 50%` + `border: 5px` - `border-box` > `50%` of available space

Again, this might be just a placeholder style. But in any case, unless you set it to `box-sizing: border-box;` the width will become `50%` + `5px` and will unexpectedly wrap.

Below are cleaned up suggestion, based on your drawing in the question.

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.main-container {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.main-container>* {
  text-align: center;
}

.shrink {
  background-color: #c0caad;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex; 
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex: 3;
}

.grow {
  background-color: #9da9a0;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex: 1;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.grow>* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #654c4f;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #b26e63;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-container">
  <div class="shrink">Shrink</div>
  <div class="grow">
    <div class="growItems">Wrap</div>
    <div class="growItems">Wrap</div>
    <div class="growItems">Wrap</div>
    <div class="growItems">Wrap</div>
    <div class="growItems">Wrap</div>
    <div class="growItems">Wrap</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what i was looking for.